# What is difference between "assert in C" and "assert in model checking like CBMC"?

Tags: c, testing, assert, model-checking

In Model checkers like CBMC(bounded model checker for C), the user-defined assert statement takes a Boolean condition, and the model checker checks whether the condition is true or false for all possible execution of the program.

In C programming, we define assert() macro with a header file assert.h. The assert() macro returns TRUE if its parameter evaluates TRUE and takes some kind of action if it evaluates FALSE. Many compilers will abort the program on an assert() that fail.

Could somebody clarify the difference between these two assertions in the Model checking and programming world?

Comment: `assert` returns `void`, although it would be helpful if it returned the value of the expression.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It can't do that in `NDEBUG` builds because the condition is never evaluated then.

Comment: @melpomene I know - I think you would have to implement this yourself. It's a fairly common thing to detect an error, handling it one way in release builds, but aborting noisily in debug.

Answer (score 3):

In model checking, assert (as you said) is verified for all possible runs (that is the primary intent for a model checker). So if it's true you'll know that the condition will always hold whatever happens. This is in the field of **formal verification**.

While in C, assert is verified at runtime, i.e. for a given instance of a run, then no guarantee that it will be true in another run. This is in the field of **testing**.

Answer (score 1):

For C it depends whether `NDEBUG` is defined when `assert.h`is included.

If `NDEBUG` is not defined an `assert` resulting in false will print a message on standard error and terminate the program.

If `NDEBUG` is defined `assert` will not generate any code, i.e. the check is skipped.

Also see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html

Answer (score 1):

Assert in C (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h) is different from assert in model checking. For e.g.,

```
    assert(x > 0);
```

In C, program gets executed and when the assert statement evaluated as false the execution aborts. In fact assert() prints an error message to standard error and terminates the program by calling abort().

In the contrary,  In fact, In model checker, the assert statement takes a Boolean condition, and checks that this condition is true for all runs of the program. In the model checking algorithm (in the case of CBMC/HiFrog, ...) there is no execution of the program (as it is part of static analysis). The model checking algorithm in a high level is as follows:

First the model checker turns the entire program together with negation of the assertion into a logical formula (Boolean, LRA, ...), and then passes the whole formula to a decision procedure such as SAT/SMT solver. If the formula is unsatisfiable (no solution) it means the assert hold in the program, x > 0 for all possible inputs of the program. Otherwise there is at least one input that make x become less than zero in assert.

As explained above, in the model checking the assert is verified for all possible runs (the primary goal for a model checker). So if model checker verifies the assert as true, we'll know that the assert statement will always hold for any arbitrary input/run of the program.